# How to conditionally assign a calculated column with the .assign method in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

How can I make conditional calculations in a merged dataframe with the .assign method in python pandas?

I would like to compare a column of two python pandas dataframes (a and b). I'm using pandas 0.25.1. After merging the dataframes into a new dataframe I use the `.assign` method to make a new column and then the lambda function to calculate the absolute and relative delta between the specified columns.

How can I make conditional calculations like this: if value_x is NaN then use -value_y, if value_y is NaN then use +value_x? For the second assign I need to calculate: if value_x is NaN then use -100, if value_y is NaN then use +100. How can I achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd

#intialise data of lists.
data_a = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'name': ['tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
    'value': [20, 21, 19, 18]
}

data_b = {
    'id': [2, 3, 4, 5],
    'name': ['nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'freddy'],
    'value': [30, 15, 19, 20]
}

# Create DataFrame
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data_a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_b)

# merge the frames
df_concat = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=['id',  'name'], how='outer')

# Calculate differences
print(df_concat.assign(delta_abs=lambda x: x.value_x -x.value_y,delta_perc=lambda x: (x.value_x/x.value_y-1)*100)) 

   id    name  value_x  value_y  delta_abs  delta_perc
0   1     tom     20.0      NaN        NaN         NaN
1   2    nick     21.0     30.0       -9.0  -30.000000
2   3   krish     19.0     15.0        4.0   26.666667
3   4    jack     18.0     19.0       -1.0   -5.263158
4   5  freddy      NaN     20.0        NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fillna()`:

```
df_concat.assign(
    delta_abs=lambda x: x.value_x.fillna(0) -x.value_y.fillna(0),
    delta_perc=lambda x: (
        x.value_x.fillna(x.value_y)/
        x.value_y.fillna(x.value_x)
    )*100
)
```

Comment: Hi @grzegorz-skibinski and thank you for you answer! fillna() was indeed what I was searching for. I slightly changed the code to return what I was looking for: 
`df_concat.assign(delta_abs=lambda x: x.value_x.fillna(0) -x.value_y.fillna(0),delta_perc=lambda x: (x.value_x.fillna(-x.value_y)/x.value_y.fillna(x.value_x))*100)`.

Comment: Maybe you could slightly change the code as I mentioned, to return the desired absolute and relative differences described in my questions. Thanks and Cheers! :-)